# Why I am not able browse sql server reporting URL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am  using sql server reporting services 2012 in my local machine
when I am trying to browser below URL 
http://xyz/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS. It gives only following output only on web page.

```
xyz/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS - /
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.2100.60
```

I am browse above url from internet explorer 10.0,with run as administrator.

why I am not able to browse entire datasource,roles/permisssion,folder to upload rdl file?

Comment: try **http ://xyz/Reports**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct url is:

```
http://xyz/Reports_SQLEXPRESS
```

the one you are using is for browsing only and does not show the full web interface.